# PHP JavaScript Bootstrap - Success/error on form field with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a field in a form that takes in an 'authorisation code' and checks it against a database using AJAX and PHP. Currently, if the authorisation code is valid it will display a tick, and a cross if wrong. I want to instead make use of the Bootstrap feedback on forms to feedback to the user if the code was wrong or not. I have validation code that so far only checks that the field is not empty on submit, using this Bootstrap method. How can I extend this so that a red outline and cross is produced if the authorisation code was wrong/vice versa if it is right? Thanks in advance for any help.

form.html:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Home</title>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/validator.js"></script>
    <script src="js/validator.min.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

<form id="auth_form" action="action.php" method="post">

  <div class="form-group has-feedback" name="auth_code" id="auth_code">
    <label for="auth_code" class="control-label">
    Authorisation Code</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="auth_code_input" name="auth_code_input" type="password">
    <span class="form-control-feedback glyphicon" id="iconBad"></span>
      <span id="auth_code_result"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-info" name="submit" type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>

<!-- AJAX -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x_timer;    
    $("#auth_code_input").keyup(function (e){
        clearTimeout(x_timer);
        var auth_code = $(this).val();
        x_timer = setTimeout(function(){
            check_auth_code_ajax(auth_code);
        }, 1000);
    }); 

function check_auth_code_ajax(auth_code){
    var $auth_code = $('#auth_code');
    $("#auth_code_result").html('<img src="img/ajax-loader.gif"/>');
    $.post('auth_code_checker.php', 
        {'auth_code_input':auth_code}, 
        function(data) {
            // data will be JSON, including a status we can use
            $("#auth_code_result").html('');
            showStatus(data.status, $auth_code);
        },
        'json'  // Expect JSON response from server
    );
}
</script>

<!-- Validating input -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('#auth_code_input').blur(function(){
      if(!ValidateInput()){
          e.preventDefault();
      }
   });

   $('#auth_form').on('submit', function(e) {
     if(!ValidateInput()){
          e.preventDefault();
      }
   })
 });

function ValidateInput(){
    var $auth_code = $('#auth_code');

    if ($auth_code.val() === "") {
        showStatus('fail', $auth_code)
        return false;
    } else {
        showStatus('ok', $auth_code)
        return true;
    } 
}

 function showStatus(status, $target) {
    if (status === 'ok') {
        $target.removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
        $('.glyphicon', $target).removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
    } else {
        $target.removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        $('.glyphicon', $target).removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
    }
}
 </script>

</body>
</html>
```

auth_code_checker.php:

```
<?php

include 'pdo_config.php';
try {
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

$auth_code = $_POST["auth_code_input"];  
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_instructors WHERE auth_code = :auth_code");
$stmt->bindParam(':auth_code', $auth_code);
$stmt->execute();

$exists = $stmt->fetchColumn();

if ($exists > 0) {
    $response['status'] = 'ok';
} else {
    $response['status'] = 'fail'; 
}

header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
echo json_encode($response);

catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be to simply re-use the same styling you already do as part of your front end validation.  To do that, extract it into a standalone function so you can call it from anywhere:

```
// Apply styles to target element based on status.  Note it expects an element
// with class .glyphicon as a child of the target, as your code has
function showStatus(status, $target) {
    if (status === 'ok') {
        $target.removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
        $('.glyphicon', $target).removeClass('glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon-ok');
    } else {
        $target.removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        $('.glyphicon', $target).removeClass('glyphicon-ok').addClass('glyphicon-remove');
    }
}
```

Now you can update your front end validation to use that:

```
function ValidateInput(){
    var $auth_code = $('#auth_code'),
        $input = $('input', $auth_code);

    if ($input.val() === "") {
        showStatus('fail', $auth_code)
        return false;
    } else {
        showStatus('ok', $auth_code)
        return true;
    } 
}
```

If you update your PHP to return some kind of success/failure status instead of an image or HTML, you can then also get your AJAX code to use the same code.  So your PHP might look like:

```
// ... your existing PHP code
if ($exists > 0) {
    $response['status'] = 'ok';
} else {
    $response['status'] = 'fail'; 
}

header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
echo json_encode($response);
```

And finally update your AJAX routine to expect that status response, and call `showStatus()` just like the front end validation:

```
function check_auth_code_ajax(auth_code){
    var $auth_code = $('#auth_code');
    $("#auth_code_result").html('<img src="img/ajax-loader.gif"/>');
    $.post('auth_code_checker.php', 
        {'auth_code_input':auth_code}, 
        function(data) {
            // data will be JSON, including a status we can use
            $("#auth_code_result").html('');
            showStatus(data.status, $auth_code);
        },
        'json'  // Expect JSON response from server
    );
}
```

Comment: Hello, this looks great, however I'm not getting a success when entering a correct code. I've edited the code in the original post to what I'm now using (your solution).

Comment: Also, in removing the AJAX from the code, it seems it still shows an error/fail message even when the field is no longer empty. Here is an updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sinesine/xqwsobmo/21/) using your code.

Comment: RE: not getting success - what do you mean? Is your PHP returning success?  RE: JSFiddle: your blur handler is missing the `e` parameter: `$('#auth_code_input').blur(function(e){`

Comment: My mistake - `$auth_code` is the parent div, not the input, so `$auth_code.val()` does not work.  I've updated `ValidateInput()` in my answer.

Comment: The code now works to validate if it is an empty field but for some reason isn't working with AJAX/PHP as it won't show an error/cross when the authorisation code is invalid?

Comment: Does your PHP return the correct response?  Check browser devtools.  Add a `console.dir(data)` in the AJAX success function, and check it on the browser console.

Comment: I think it may also be best to remove the success outline/tick that shows when the field is no longer empty as it suggests the authorisation code is valid when it may not be?

Comment: I'll check that now.

Comment: The console says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: So you have a JS syntax error somewhere ... did you find it?

Comment: Yes, I managed to find it. Still no success with the server side aspect however. I'm going to revise the code and look at it again later today. Thanks for all your help

Comment: You're welcome - please consider accepting my answer if it answered your question, thanks.